# TortoiseHg with word diffs and LaTeX

Tags: highlighting, revision-control

I am having a hard time figuring out how to configure TortoiseHg to do colored word diffs for my TeX and LaTeX documents. I found the following two threads

- [How to use Mercurial for version control of text documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147906/how-to-use-mercurial-for-version-control-of-text-documents)
- [Good strategy for line breaks with paragraphs of LaTeX source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/good-strategy-for-line-breaks-with-paragraphs-of-latex-source)

but they don't go in detail how to to set this up on TortoiseHg. I was wondering if anybody in the TeX/LaTeX community has figured this out already?