# Justify the TeX-code from the editor

Tags: best-practices, editors

Maybe it's the writer (or the editor) who should be capable of this. But anyway, I wonder if I can do that with TeX.

I usually want my TeX-code to appear somehow justified. Is there a way to do that?

Precisely I would like to avoid the chaos:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, 
placerat ac,  $\int$ 
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna.
```

and want to find a way so that my code **automatically** looks more or less justified (after I wrote most of it):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut 
purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, $\int$ adipiscing vitae,
felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy 
eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue
```

I'm using Kile (but I wouldn't mind to use another just to open the code there and then work back in Kile).

Comment: You are asking a question about an editor but not said what editor you are using `M-q` will do that in emacs for example

Comment: [personal opinion] Since justification of your source file and of your generated document won't match, I'm circumspect about justifying in your IDE. I personally use the [one sentence per line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/good-strategy-for-line-breaks-with-paragraphs-of-latex-source) approach, that, if not mandatory, is easier to use with version-control and make easy to find again the line of code related to the part of your document you'd like to change.

Comment: See also [When you write TeX source, how do you use your editor's word wrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899114/when-you-write-tex-source-how-do-you-use-your-editors-word-wrap) and [Editing files with one-sentence-per-line](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/443)

Comment: Maybe is too late for one sentence per line approach, since my document is written.

Comment: Any editor will show the text the way you want if you use a "one paragraph per line" approach. That is to delete all the `newline` codes at the end of each line in either 1st or 2nd code above. This can be done with a succession of `sed` or `tr` or `awk` commands or python script etc, whatever you're comfortable with. Same thing if you want a "one sentence per line" (which will not lead to a nearly justified look).

Answer (score 2):

I installed `emacs`, opened my `.tex` document there and used `M-q` as in the comments was suggested. In principle, it works. But `M-q` doesn't care about the `%`-commented lines, so that approach is not 100% safe.

Otherwise, installing AUCTeX, it works.

Comment: »But `M-q` doesn't care about the `%`-commented lines« – it does when you use AUCTeX with emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I made a python script to convert sloppy input text (like the "chaos" example above) into a "one paragraph per line" text that will be displayed almost justified (word-wrapped) by any editor.
Also useful when the text is extracted from pdf files or imported from other 
software.

I wanted to keep it as simple as possible and easy to understand/modify by anyone without python knowledge (like me :)).

**Notes**: Please do not use on preambles or other TeX command blocks. Extract only the relevant text on a separate file. 
Please **backup your work** before using the script!!

**The python script** (not tested on windows hosts or texts):

```
#
# script name:      oneParagraphPerLine.py
# python version:   2 or 3 
# usage:            python oneParagraphPerLine.py infile # this will print the output to screen
# usage:            python oneParagraphPerLine.py infile >> outfile # this will redirect the output to "outfile"
# description:      this script converts sloppy input text into a "paragraph per line" text (mostly in TeX source files) 
#                   also usefull when importing text from other software or extracting text from pdfs.
#                   don't run it on preamble or heavy [La]TeX code, it will mess up things!
#

import sys

try:
    infile = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:                           # stop if no infile given
    print ('Please provide a file to convert.') 
    exit()

with open(infile) as file:
    newline = True                           # an indicator showing if the last line printed ended with a CR
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()                 # remove trailing whitespaces
        if (
            line.startswith(('\\', '$'))     # for lines starting with a command, or inline math; add comma sepparated strings
            or line == ""                    # or empty lines
            or "%" in line                   # or lines with comments (it will trigger on \% though)
            ):
            if not newline: sys.stdout.write('\n') # if the last line was not ending with a CR, insert one
            sys.stdout.write(line + '\n')    # print the line (it has a CR)
            newline = True                   # update the indicator
        else:
            line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')  # remove linux and windows CR, LF
            sys.stdout.write(line + ' ')     # print the line with a space after it (no CR)
            newline = False                  # tell the indicator we printed a line without a CR
if not newline: sys.stdout.write('\n')       # in case last line printed had no CR
# that's it
```

The test **input file** was based on the "chaos" example above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

 \newcommand\multiline{
     It will mess up multiline commands, better don't try!!!
     }

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.    
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,    
placerat ac,  $\int$      
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,  
magna. 


Two empty lines above test.

A line with a comment % comment
should remain as it is but   
it will trigger on percent signs,
like 100\%,   
as well because there might be lines with both 100\% and a comment% like this one - its doable though

An 
$ inline \ math $
purposely placed on a separate line
should remain as it is.

% comment line.
\end{document}
```

The **output file**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

 \newcommand\multiline{      It will mess up multiline commands, better don't try!!!      } 

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,  $\int$ adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 


Two empty lines above test. 

A line with a comment % comment
should remain as it is but it will trigger on percent signs, 
like 100\%,
as well because there might be lines with both 100\% and a comment% like this one - its doable though

An 
$ inline \ math $
purposely placed on a separate line should remain as it is. 

% comment line.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does it do with code that has an equation within a paragraph or with an already nicely indented itemize or something?

Comment: Willing to file a bug?:) As said, this is for sloppy text (like when extracting from pdf), not for nicely written code. It's a simple code you can apply to parts of your source file (not necessarily tex), more for literature than scientific docs (where word-wrapping doesn't make too much sense anyway). @clemens

Comment: Ok. I was just curious :)

Comment: That's why I included the `\multiline` example in the test file, to show it won't work. It's not intended to be an interpreter. It can be attached to a shortcut, select the bit of text to be converted in your [GUI] editor, and convert it on the spot. @clemens